# Generic json schema for two condition based responses

Tags: jsonschema

I have an API returning response based on input type.

For a single filter I get

```json
{
    "intervalData": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2021-05-25T06:00:00.000Z",
            "result": {
                "Attempts": 309194
            }
        }
    ],
    "intervalTotals": {
        "Attempts": 4719471
    }
}
```

For multiple filter I get

```json
{
  "multiFilterData": [
        {
            "filter": {
                "id": 111111
            },
            "intervalData": {
                "timestamp": "2021-05-25T20:41:39.000Z",
                "result": {
                    "Attempts": 7902
                }
            }
        },
        {...}
    ]
}
```

That means the response will either have (`intervalData`,`intervalTotals`) OR `multiFilterData`.

**Question:**

1. Is it possible to have a generic schema to handle this or must I have two separate schemas?
2. How to make sure that if one combination is present other should not be there?

I tried with below schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/. The validation fails if there is some other keys listed under the required, unfortunately the validation succeeds if one of the entry from `oneOf` is missing. **EDIT1 below**

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "intervalData",
        "intervalTotals",
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "multiFilterData",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "intervalData": {
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "timestamp",
          "result"
        ],
        "properties": {
          ...
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    },
    "intervalTotals": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "Attempts"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Attempts": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "multiFilterData": {
      "type": "array",
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "filter",
          "intervalData"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "filter": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "id"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          },
          "intervalData": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "timestamp",
              "result"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "timestamp": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "result": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "Attempts"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  ...
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

**EDIT 1:** This schema also passes even though the first required is missing an element on the list.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "intervalData"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "multiFilterData",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "intervalData": {...},
    "intervalTotals": {...},
    "multiFilterData": {...}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: "if there is some other keys listed under the required" - can you provide an example of failures that should pass or passes that should fail?

Comment: Both the instances you have provided pass validation for the second schema you have provided. I'll vote to close till an update is provided, as currently further information is required to reproduce your issue fully.

Comment: As you're using draft-07, you may consider using https://jsonschema.dev shareable links.